# Elastic regexp filter on more than one field

Tags: elasticsearch

the following example creates a filtered alias for any document in which the **title** field contains "smith".

How can you create an alias that is filtered for a second field such as **title OR description**?

["title","description"] does not work as I expected it to and I can not use the _all as it gives the incorrect results.

```
curl -XPOST 'http://localhost:9200/_aliases' -d '{
    "actions" : [
        {
            "add" : {
                 "index" : "myindex",
                 "alias" : "smithbooks",
                 "filter" : { "regexp" : { "title" : "smith" } } 
            }
        }
    ]
}'
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this using an OR filter which can be found here:

http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/query-dsl-or-filter.html